# Como faço para que uma pessoa não possa reservar o quarto no mesmo dia?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho o código da reserva feita, mas o SELECT que é para que as pessoas não possam reservar o quarto no mesmo dia eu não consigo fazer. Na minha base de dados tenho a tabela reserva, na qual se encontram os dados.

> cod_reserva,nome,email,n_telef, checkin, checkout,nr_adultos, tipo_quarto,precoT

Aqui tenho o código:

```
 <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hotel");

    $nome=$_POST['Nome'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $telefone=$_POST['telefone'];
    $checkin=$_POST['checkin'];
    $checkout=$_POST['checkout'];
    $nr_adultos=$_POST['nr_adultos'];
    //$n_noites=$_POST['n_noites'];

    $tipo_quarto=$_POST['tipo_quarto'];
    $precoT=$_POST['pre']; 

        // verificacao de dados e feito em javascript e/ou html php so para comunicacao com servidor;

    $query = "INSERT INTO reserva VALUES (NULL, '$nome', '$email', $telefone, '$checkin', '$checkout', $nr_adultos,'$tipo_quarto',$precoT)";
    $result = mysqli_query ($link ,  $query);

    if($result){
        echo "<script> myFunction('Reserva feita'); </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script> myFunction('Erro ao fazer a reserva'); </script>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Você deve fazer uma verificação com um SELECT. Usando como critério no Where o ID a Pessoa, o Quarto e a Data de Entrada e Saída.

Comment: Diego eu comentei , pode ver o que fiz de mal pf v?

Comment: esta com erro ainda? coloca o CREATE da sua tabela ai que te ajudo

Comment: A pergunta não está clara, você quer restringir que uma única pessoa faça mais de uma reserva por dia? ou você quer que para cada quarto tenha somente uma reserva?

Comment: É inconcebível você migrar o seu sistema e.g. para o PostgreSQL? O PostgreSQL têm tipos que representam intervalos temporais e [índices EXCLUDE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) que impedem, no nível do banco de dados, que você insira duas reservas com intervalos conflitantes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considerando que os campos `checkin` e `checkout` são as datas, você tem algumas alternativas:

1) Definir um índice único no banco de dados com os campos: `nome, checkin`, desta forma a pessoa não faz duas reservas no mesmo dia.

2) Fazer uma pesquisa no banco antes da inserção, usando o sql:

```
 select * from reserva where nome = '" . $nome . "' and checkin = '" . $$checkin . "'
```

Caso a pesquisa encontre um resultado, não faz a reserva.

**Problemas**

- Duas pessoas podem ter o mesmo nome, ex: João da Silva
- A mesma pessoa pode digitar seu nome de forma diferente em cada reserva, imaginando, pelo seu código, que por você estar utilizando uma tela de entrada onde a pessoa digita seu nome de forma aberta

Uma solução seria solicitar na tela a digitação do cpf, sem espaços e pontos. Desta forma fica mais seguro fazer o índice ou a pesquisa pelo cpf associado à data.

---

**Outra** consideração, se você pretende testar o intervalo de checkin e checkout, usa a pesquisa com as seguintes comparações após a clausula WHERE:

```
$checkin . "' >= checkin AND " . $checkin . "' <= checkout"
```

Considerando que você já fez a validação para que a data de checkin seja menor ou igual à checkout

Comment: -1 pelo SQL injection

Comment: Por favor @ctgPi, edite a resposta evitando o SQL injection ao invés de criticar diretamente, pois sua negativa não ajuda o colega que está  perguntando